# Craft brew in Dublin

Tags: breweries, micropub

Other than the popular Porterhouse (http://www.porterhousebrewco.com/bars-dublin-temple.php), are there other pub that serves craft/microbrewery beer in Dublin, Ireland?

Other than the famous Guinness brewhouse, are there other microbrewery around Dublin?

Other than Guinness Stout, what other Guinness beer is a must-have? Are there any Dublin exclusive beer?

Answer (score 1):

Try against the grain on wexford street got a good selection there

Comment: I'd be interested in any other microbreweries in Ireland. The Porterhouse is a refreshing change. A nice beer from the Guinness brewhouse was called North Star. I don't know if they still brew it but I saw it in Galway. This was about 7 years ago.

Answer (score -1):

Try the J.W. Sweetman Craft Brewery on 1-2 Burgh Quay. Just after O'Connel Bridge.